Out of Heap Memory Error when Generating Multiple PDFs using Itext7 library in Java
I have a Java method that generates PDFs from HTML templates using the iText 7 library. The method works fine for generating a small number of PDFs, but when I try to run this code with 10 threads and generating a large number (e.g., 1000), I encounter an out-of-memory error.Heap size increasing upto 1GB.
And also i am using a base64 String of Signature and Letterhead images.
Java

public byte[] startPdfCreation(String template, PdfConfiguration configuration, Map<String, String> notice) {
    try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream);
      PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
      pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
      Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
      document.setLeftMargin(26);
      document.setRightMargin(26);

      String letterhead = getLetterheadImage(configuration);
      pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new BackgroundImageHandler(letterhead));
      String signature = getSignatureImage(configuration);
      ConverterProperties properties = getConverterProperties();
      String substitutedTemplate = substituteValues(template, notice);

      List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(substitutedTemplate, properties);
      for (IElement element : elements) {
        document.add((BlockElement) element);
      }
      document.close();
      pdfDocument.close();
      return outputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("error while creating a pdf", e);
    }
    return new byte[0];
  }

Here i am using executor service to run in 10 threads
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
    CompletableFuture<Void> allTasks = CompletableFuture.allOf(
        noticeDataList.stream()
            .map(notice -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
              PdfConfiguration pdfConfiguration = createPdfConfiguration(notice);
              byte[] fileContent = startPdfCreation(template, pdfConfiguration, notice);
              Map<String, String> uploadResponse = uploadPdf(fileContent, notice);
              if (uploadResponse != null) {
                successFiles.add(notice);
              } else {
                failedFiles.add(notice);
              }
            }, executor))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)
    );
    return allTasks.thenApply(result -> {
      executor.shutdown();
      return new PdfGenerateResponse(successFiles, failedFiles);
    }).join();

Is there is something i am missing or what please help me out
Thanks.
How i can create upto 1000 pdf using Threads in minimum heap memory usage.

Write to temp files or upload direct to destination rather than make a huge memory footprint for each pdf.

@DuncG yes you are correct but i want to upload this pdf to aws s3 bucket thats why i want to write this to in memory

WIthout profiling it will be hard to determine the problem.  How large are the individual PDF files?  What happens if you limit the threads to, say, 4?  There's really not enough info here for anybody to help you at this point.
